# Where should an array of config values be stored in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array of Google Font settings that looks like this:

```
$googleFontList = array(
    'Abril Fatface' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Abril+Fatface',
        'css_name' => 'Abril Fatface',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Archivo Narrow' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Archivo+Narrow:400italic,400,700italic,700',
        'css_name' => 'Archivo Narrow',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Arvo' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Arvo:400italic,400,700italic,700',
        'css_name' => 'Arvo',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Crete Round' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Crete+Round:400italic,400',
        'css_name' => 'Crete Round',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Droid Serif' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Droid+Serif:400italic,400,700italic,700',
        'css_name' => 'Droid Serif',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Josefin Slab' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Josefin+Slab:400,400italic,700,700italic',
        'css_name' => 'Josefin Slab',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Lato' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Lato:400italic,400,700,700italic',
        'css_name' => 'Lato',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Merriweather' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Merriweather:400italic,400,700italic,700',
        'css_name' => 'Merriweather',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Open Sans' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Open+Sans:400,400italic,700italic,700',
        'css_name' => 'Open Sans',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Oswald' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Oswald:400,700',
        'css_name' => 'Oswald',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Roboto' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic',
        'css_name' => 'Roboto',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Roboto Condensed' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Roboto+Condensed:400,400italic,700,700italic',
        'css_name' => 'Roboto Condensed',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Roboto Slab' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Roboto+Slab:400,400italic,700,700italic',
        'css_name' => 'Roboto Slab',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Ubuntu' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Ubuntu:400,400italic,700,700italic',
        'css_name' => 'Ubuntu',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
    'Varela Round' => array(
        'link_code' => 'Varela+Round',
        'css_name' => 'Varela Round',
        'normal_weight' => 400,
        'bold_weight' => 700,
    ),
);
```

I would like to avoid having to place this array in multiple different controller methods. Where could/should I put something like this so that it can later be called into controllers? Could this live in a config file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a new config file, e.g. `data.php` in config folder .Just return an array like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'key' => 'value',
];
```

You can get this variable by

```
Config::get('data.key');
```